# Calling a function from another function Jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I'm working on a website for kids where they can play a simple Higher-Lower game with cards programmed in Jquery. I'm stuck on one particular part of my code though. I could fix it by writing a mass of double code, but there has to be a more efficient way to do it.

Edit: So the real question is, how do I call one function from another? Like a method.

I want to call my Kaartgenereren function from my Hoger() function.

```
function KaartGenereren() {...}
```

This is how I tried to call the function:

```
function Hoger(){
                oudekaart = kaartnummer;

                do{
                    $.Kaartgenereren(); ...}while(...)}
```

I've also tried it without the $. and the (), but it led to no result.

I hope someone will be able to help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI Javascript is case-sensitive so if your function is called `KartGenereren` you should make sure the K and G are capitalized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way is

```
KaartGenereren();
```

but you have to fix a typo first

```
Kaartgenereren vs KaartGenereren
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I could've searched for hours to find that typo :)

Comment: Just use your javascript console.   It would have told you right away that the function was not defined.

Comment: I did, and it said so indeed. But I assumed it would have something to do with functions not being recognised in other functions. (I'm very new to Jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
function Hoger(){
    oudekaart = kaartnummer;
    do {
        KaartGenereren();
        ...
    } while(...);
}
```

Comment: You missed the function name's typo when it's called.